# R: Insert and fill missing periods in panel data

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I'm trying to learn R coming from Stata, but have run into the following two problems which I cannot seem to find elegant solutions for in R:

1) I have a panel dataset with gaps in my time variable. I would like to expand my time variable to include the gaps despite having no observed data for these rows.

In Stata I would usually go about this by setting my ID and time variables with `xtset` and then expanding the dataset based on this with `tsfill`. Is there an equivalently elegant way in R?

2) I would like to fill some of the new, blank cells with data for constant variables.

In Stata I would do this by copying data from previous (relative to my time variable) observations using the `l.`-prefix; for example using `replace Con = l.Con`.

In other words I'm asking how to go from something like this:

```
ID     Time     Num     Con
1      Jan      10      A
1      Feb      15      A
1      May      20      A
2      Feb      12      B
2      Mar      14      B
2      Jun      15      B
```

To something like this:

```
ID     Time     Num     Con
1      Jan      10      A
1      Feb      15      A
1      Mar              A
1      Apr              A
1      May      20      A
2      Feb      12      B
2      Mar      14      B
2      Apr              B
2      May              B
2      Jun      15      B
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `merge` from `base R` or the `data.table` join

```
 library(data.table)
 DT2 <- setDT(df1)[, {tmp <- match(Time, month.abb)
      list(Time=month.abb[min(tmp):max(tmp)])}, .(ID,Con)]
 setkey(df1[, c(1,4,2,3), with=FALSE], ID, Con, Time)[DT2]
 #    ID Con Time Num
 # 1:  1   A  Jan  10
 # 2:  1   A  Feb  15
 # 3:  1   A  Mar  NA
 # 4:  1   A  Apr  NA
 # 5:  1   A  May  20
 # 6:  2   B  Feb  12
 # 7:  2   B  Mar  14
 # 8:  2   B  Apr  NA
 # 9:  2   B  May  NA
 #10:  2   B  Jun  15
```

NOTE: It may be better to keep missing value as `NA`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use fill() function or complete() function in R to fill missing gaps in panel data. The fill() function requires you to convert data in tsibble first, and then fill these missing gaps. Complete function, on the other hand, is part of tidyverse package and can directly fill the missing gaps in panel data.
To read more https://thedatahall.com/filling-gaps-in-time-series-and-panel-data-using-r/

Comment: The link is a helpful source, but you should included code showing the implementation of these function. The OP has provided a reproducible example with sample data along with expected output you can match. `complete()` *and* `fill()` are functions from the package `tidyr`, which is part of the tidyverse. So both functions are from the tidyverse. If you are referencing a different `fill()` function you should specify the package.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35680592)